# Modbus address unknown Temperature controller data read by PLC

Tags: serial-port, ascii, modbus, plc, rs485

A temperature controller module sends data as RS485-Modbus Ascii code. When used putty 2400bps,parity-None,stop bit-1. Data shown as  `0036 0030$*  0036 0030$*  0036 0030$*` on serial monitor of putty. I need to get this information to PLC. But I do not know Modbus station ID, Address.

Is there is a way to find unknown device's Modbus station ID & Address?

[image: putty serial data view]

I used Modscan, Modbus Poll but no success.

Comment: The output in the screenshot does not look like Modbus Ascii to me. You will need to provide further information (it's not clear what you mean by "station ID & Address" - do you mean the Modbus slave address?).

Comment: Yes, @Brits Modbus RTU mode uses station ID & Address. I could not find info on Modbus ascii.seems It just communiacte via serial port on given communication 2400bps.Hence I've created a python code to read serial data in a GUI as other option.

Comment: The Modbus specs (including ASCII) are [available here](https://modbus.org/specs.php). The RTU spec does not use the term "Station", I suspect you mean slave number.